# Snapchat SDK getting stuck on completion page Swift/Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, info.plist, snapchat

so I'm working on an app right now where I need to add snapchat login. To do this, I am using their LoginKit SnapSDK. I implemented it as instructed, but when a user tries to log in, they don't go to the snapchat app but rather it opens a safari popup. This wouldn't be an issue if it worked, but it doesn't. The user can put in their credentials, but on the last page they are prompted with a "continue" button that doesn't do anything. Because it does nothing, the user is never logged in and the popup doesn't close. Below I have attached my code (very simple), an image of my Info.plist, and an image of my Frameworks.

Code:

```
SCSDKLoginClient.login(from: self) { success, error in
    if let error = error {
        // An error occurred during the login process
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        self.dismiss(animated: true)
        self.getUserInfo()
    }
}
```

[image: Info.plist]

[image: Frameworks, etc]

Comment: Hello, are you working or real device or simulator?

Comment: @Romy I am working on a real device with the newest version of snapchat installed

Comment: Is strange I get the same error on a simulator. I can only say try to delete the pods and reinstall. But I think is not a solution

Comment: @Romy do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Aidan your side snapchat login successfully works fine.if its fine then please share any sample project link

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in your `info.plist`

for `item 3` in `LSApplicationQueriesSchema` which is `rocket` should be part of URLScheme. Remove that `rocket` and put it in URLSchemes

[image]

You can just copy this code

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>rocket</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

As for frameworks make sure it looks like this

[image]